# Does not appear smartWall advertising airpush

Tags: android, airpush

Does not appear smartWall advertising airpush

```
import com.devmobby.dbel.R;
import com.fxxylrmjq.hnqqtdyue156508.AdCallbackListener;
import com.fxxylrmjq.hnqqtdyue156508.AirPlay;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Test extends Activity implements AdCallbackListener{
    private AirPlay airPlay; //Declare AirPlay here

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(airPlay==null)
            airPlay=new AirPlay(this, null, true);

            airPlay.startSmartWallAd();
    }


    @Override
    public void onAdCached(AdType adType) {
         airPlay.showCachedAd(this, AdType.appwall);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdError(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSDKIntegrationError(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSmartWallAdClosed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSmartWallAdShowing() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoAdFinished() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoAdShowing() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: dont bother - airpush is a scam - they don't pay!!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the airpush ad loads only for 3 times a day. and the smartwall as well.
I think so just add the airpush code to the project and leave it because it will display as you want. Better to check ur code in other device too.
I suggest to use [Admob](http://www.google.co.in/ads/admob/)
to advertise and earn money, rather than Airpush

Answer (score 0):

Caching is messy. Use airPlay=new AirPlay(this, null, <strike>true</strike> false);